# confirm box from a controller

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

Have a requirement to call the confirm box in JSP, following is my code in controller,

```
    if(!(nesting)){
        bla.add("Do you want to Load anyway?");
        context.getFlowScope().put("bla", bla); 
        context.getFlowScope().put("uldSelector", uldSelector); 
        return;
        }                       
h = uloService.processDomBatch(histInfo, dl, items);
```

the above will add the error to flowscope and returns, but, I wantto call a confirm box instead and then depending yes/no, I should continue through...

is there a way to do this?..any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @user1609085 you can do it with `AJAX` and `JavaScript` something like this:

```
function question(val) {
    var chk = document.forms[0].chk
    var box = valBox(chk)
    var resp = confirm("Do you want to Load anyway?")
    if(resp) {
        if(box == null) { return }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'controllerMethod?action=controllerMethod',
                data: 'uldSelector='+val,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("histInfo")
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('ERROR: ' + data)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

    function valBox(b) {
        var cnt = -1
        for(var i = b.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            if(b[i].checked) {
                cnt = i
                i = -1
            }
        }
        if(cnt > -1) return b[cnt].value
        else return null
    }
```

And you box only put `onclick="question(this.value)"`

**I hope help you :)**